# Call function inside of the other function in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I am really new to Haskell. I have two functions for array of tuples. Fist one replaces Bool value with 0 or 1.

```
boolToInt :: [([Char], Bool)] -> [([Char], Int)]
boolToInt ((x, True):xs)        = (x, 1): boolToInt xs
boolToInt ((x, False):xs)       = (x, 0): boolToInt xs
boolToInt []                    = []
```

Second sums the second values in the list

```
teamNumberOfWins :: [([Char], Int)] -> Int
teamNumberOfWins  []            = 0
teamNumberOfWins ((x, y):xs)    = sum + y
   where sum = teamNumberOfWins xs
```

For the second function list has to be already with Int values. Is there a way to call in second function first one? I tried something like this:

```
teamNumberOfWins :: [([Char], Int)] -> Int
teamNumberOfWins  []            = 0
teamNumberOfWins ((x, y):xs)    = sum + y
   where sum = teamNumberOfWins (boolToInt xs)
```

but it doesn't work. Can someone help me?

Comment: The input type should contain booleans if you want to call the first function. Also, you don't need to convert the whole list at each recursive call: converting once is enough.

Comment: @chi, in what place should i call the function once? I was thinking something like that but i don't where to do it.

Comment: `sum [if b then 1 else 0 | (_, b) in ls]`?

Comment: @Seiggailion Robin below showed how to do it: you can define `f ys = f2 (boolToInt ys) where f2 [] = ... ; f2 (x:xs) = ...`. The point is, you need to define an auxiliary recursive function (`f2` above) working on "list with ints", and then call that with the modified list.

Comment: Note that you don't actually need `boolToInt`, because `Bool` already has an `Enum` instance, which lets you write `teamNumberOfWins = ((x,y):xs) = fromEnum y + teamNumberOfWins xs`, or using Elmex80's list comprehension, `sum [fromEnum b | (_, b) <- ls]`. (Which itself is just `teamNumberOfWins = sum . map (fromEnum . snd)`.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your defenition:

```
teamNumberOfWins :: [([Char], Int)] -> Int
teamNumberOfWins  []            = 0
teamNumberOfWins ((x, y):xs)    = sum + y
   where sum = teamNumberOfWins (boolToInt xs)
```

there is a problem with the last line. `xs` is a value of type `[([Char], Int)]`, but `boolToInt` has only been defined to work on values of type `[([Char], Bool)]`. Haskell has a very strict type system (which is actually one of the language's strengths), and simply won't allow you to do this.

What you clearly want to do is to take a list of type `[([Char], Bool)]`, and apply `boolToInt`, then apply `teamNumberOfWins` (your original version), to the result. This is called function composition, and Haskell has a very helpful built-in function/operator to do this, which is simply `.`

So all you need to do is keep your first 2 functions as they are, and define a new one:

```
teamNumberOfWins' = teamNumberOfWins . boolToInt
```

Note that you can also drastically simplify the definition of `boolToInt` using the `map` function, which applies a function of one element to every element of a list. Thus:

```
boolToInt = map singleBoolToInt
  where singleBoolToInt (x, True) = (x, 1)
        singleBoolToInt (x, False) = (x, 0)
```

Comment: Imo it's worth introducing `fromEnum` for `singleBoolToInt`

Comment: If we want to simplify further, we can let `teamNumberOfWins = length . filter snd`. But I like Robin's answer since it _explains_ to the OP what's wrong, and proposes a fix which should be understandable to the OP. By comparison, just giving out a cryptic solution as mine won't be very helpful, at least until the OP learns some intermediate Haskell.

Comment: Thanks @chi, and @ATayler - I agree with your comments, I didn't pursue the simplification beyond the `map`, in part because of laziness and time constraints, and also in part because I'm nowhere near as familiar with Haskell myself as you guys. (Should definitely have spotted the `length . filter snd` version though.) Mainly i wanted to show the OP specifically what he was doing wrong, and the most "direct" (although not the "best") way to fix it.